# python dataframe - creating new column based on substring conditions in another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a simplified dataframe with one department_name column. I want to create a new column in the same dataframe which stores the "Region" value. The criteria will search in department_name (a) strip content from '-' onwards. e.g. "ABC Europe - Team A" will be stored as "ABC Europe" as a new value. in "Region" (b) If there is no '-', then entire string is retained. (c) if department_name  is empty, then set new value to "Others".

Currently I am doing a very crude and hard code of search and replace, which is not the correct way to do. Seeking advice on how to do elegant approach to it (possibly if conditions?), if possible avoiding regex please.

| Department_Name |
| --- |
| ABC Europe - Team A |
| ABC Europe - Team B |
| TRD Europe - Team C |
| TDC Europe - Team A |
| XXX Asia - Team A |
| XXX EMEA - Team D |
| HQ |
|  |

| Department_Name | Region |
| --- | --- |
| ABC Europe - Team A | ABC Europe |
| ABC Europe - Team B | ABC Europe |
| TRD Europe - Team C | TRD Europe |
| TDC Europe - Team A | TDC Europe |
| XXX Asia - Team A | XXX Asia |
| XXX EMEA - Team D | XXX EMEA |
| HQ | HQ |
|  | Others |

Answer (score 0):

Vectorized Pandas str methods will be fastest:

```
d = {
    'Department_Name' : ['ABC Europe - Team A', 'ABC Europe - Team B',
                        'TRD Europe - Team C', 'TDC Europe - Team A', 
                        'XXX Asia - Team A' ,'XXX EMEA - Team D', 'HQ',
                         '', np.nan]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
# create series with pre '-' value
dep = df['Department_Name'].str.split('-').str[0].str.strip()
# fill blanks/nulls with 'Others'
df['Region'] = dep.replace('', 'Others').fillna('Others')
print(df)
```